# Hive Reading a sequence File

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am having an issue regarding the binary data i see in Hive tables when querying a table stored as Sequencefile format.

I used Sqoop to import data from Databse specified following options:

```
--as-sequencefile --fields-terminated-by '\001' --null-string '\\N' --null-non-string '
```

created a Hive external table to point to the location i imported DB Data:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE if not exists Test(
test_id string,
s_date timestamp)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\001'
STORED AS sequencefile 
LOCATION '<location where i importedsqoop data>
```

I was thinking that my Hive tabe would deserialize data and display the data in a readable format but i see data as a binary or non-readable foramt.

Do i need any more steps to be followed in order for hive to deserialize the data?

Thank you. Nish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the sequence file output of Sqoop is not compatible with the Hive default SerDe for sequence file.  There is a Github project [Hive-Sqoop-Serde](https://github.com/jorisbontje/Hive-Sqoop-Serde) that might be what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to declare input and output formats as well. Create the table like this:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE if not exists Test(
test_id string,
s_date timestamp)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\001'
STORED AS sequencefile 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveSequenceFileOutputFormat'
LOCATION '<location where i importedsqoop data>
```